# foreach instead of FOR IN R

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

I am a freshman of R. I want to execute randomForest in R and the data has 1000 rows and 28 columns. The idea is to test all mtry (1:27) and each of them will be tested by 10 repeats 10-fold CV. The problem is it takes such a long time and still no result! I try to use 'foreach' loop instead of 'for', but I do not know how to do it. The codes is shown below:

```
library(randomForest)
n <- nrow(data)
a1 <- 1:n
a2 <- rep(1:10,ceiling(n/10))[1:n]
k <- ncol(data)-1    
trainrf <- testrf <- list()
for(i in 1:k){    # tune mtry from 1 to 27
    rftrain <- rftest <- NULL
    for(x in 1:10){   # 10 repeats 10-fold CV
        set.seed(1981)
        a2 <- sample(a2,n)
        train.rf <- test.rf <- rep(0,10)
        for(j in  1:10){
            m <- a1[a2 == j]
            n1 <- n-length(m)
            n2 <- length(m)
            set.seed(2013)
            rf.data <- randomForest(level~., data=data[-m,], mtry=i, ntree=1000)
            train.rf[j] <- sum(data[-m,28] == predict(rf.data, data[-m,]))/n1
            test.rf[j] <- sum(data[m,28] == predict(rf.data, data[m,]))/n2
        }
        rftrain[x] <- mean(train.rf); rftest[x] <- mean(test.rf)
    }
    trainrf[[i]] <- rftrain; testrf[[i]] <- rftest
}
```

My laptop is i7 Windows 7 64-bit, and I wrote a few codes as I know:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, your example does not seem to make use of foreach at all, so I'm not sure what to correct. Also ntree=1000 is quite large and is likely why you are seeing such a long delay. Have you tried starting with a smaller forest?

Comment: If you don't know how to du it, you should read some of the vignettes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should read some of the `foreach` vignettes, since although this is a fairly straight-forward use of `foreach`, it is not trivial, like many examples.

Here's my attempt at translating your script to `foreach`, although I couldn't test it since your example isn't reproducible:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
n <- nrow(data)
a1 <- 1:n
a2 <- rep(1:10,ceiling(n/10))[1:n]
k <- ncol(data)-1
outercomb <- function(...) {
    lapply(1:2, function(i) lapply(list(...), function(p) p[[i]]))
}
innercomb <- function(...) {
    lapply(1:2, function(i) sapply(list(...), function(p) p[[i]]))
}
r <- foreach(i=1:k, .combine='outercomb', .multicombine=TRUE,
        .packages='randomForest') %:%
    foreach(1:10, .combine='innercomb', .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
        set.seed(1981)
        Xa2 <- sample(a2, n)
        train.rf <- double(10)
        test.rf <- double(10)
        for(j in  1:10){
            m <- a1[Xa2 == j]
            n1 <- n-length(m)
            n2 <- length(m)
            set.seed(2013)
            rf.data <- randomForest(level~., data=data[-m,], mtry=i, ntree=1000)
            train.rf[j] <- sum(data[-m,28] == predict(rf.data, data[-m,]))/n1
            test.rf[j] <- sum(data[m,28] == predict(rf.data, data[m,]))/n2
        }
        c(mean(train.rf), mean(test.rf))
    }
trainrf <- r[[1]]
testrf <- r[[2]]
```

Here are some comments:

- You should investigate the `caret` package.  I think it can do this kind of stuff for you quite easily, and it uses `foreach` to do it in parallel.
- Although I'm parallelizing across the outer two loops, if you have access to a cluster, you probably can go further.  There's a lot of parallelism here.
- This uses nested foreach loops which are an advanced feature, but very useful for this kind of problem.
- I used `Xa2` instead of `a2` to emphasize that the `foreach` loop cannot update the variable `a2` across loop iterations.  I'm not sure if my version does what you want, so you'll have to think about that.
- The `.combine` functions are a bit tricky, but are needed in order to produce two results.  They both perform a transpose of sorts.
- You should avoid the formula interface to `randomForest` since it uses more memory and can be slow.
- I assume that your use of `set.seed` is only for testing.

Comment: Sorry this is off topic from the question but what do you mean when you say that the formula interface of `randomForrest` should be avoided?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor There are two S3 methods for `randomForest`: one for class "formula", and the default method that takes a data frame or matrix and a response vector.  The formula version uses more memory and I've heard Andy Liaw say that it's caused him a lot of problems.

Comment: I had to stare at the CRAN page of randomForest for like 5 minutes before I saw what you're talking about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't execute your example, because `data` is not defined. But maybe a minimal `foreach`-example may help:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

testList <- foreach(i=1:5) %dopar% {
  1:i
}
```

The result of each run from `i=1:5` is combined to a list and saved in the variable `testList`:

```
> testList
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

You could specify another combine method with:

```
> testList <- foreach(i=1:5, .combine="c") %dopar% {
+   1:i
+ }
> 
> testList
 [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

I think you have to do two `foreach` loops, one for `trainrf` and one for `testrf`